# Trying to run OpenGL on Linux, have the necessary libraries but won't run? (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glut

I am new to Linux and am currently using Linux Mint. I followed the instructions on [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182109/Setting-up-an-OpenGL-development-environment-in-Ub), however whenever I go to compile the example code (given on the web page), the build fails.

`g++ ~/Desktop/test.cpp -lglut` gives me the following:

`/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3aKYsD.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glOrtho'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Why does this keep occurring? I apologize for such a beginner question, but this is irritating.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link with the OpenGL library as well:

```
g++ ~/Desktop/test.cpp -lglut -lGL
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I knew it was something simple.